# How to POST xml data while calling API through JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, post, certificate, logic

I am creating an application where I want to POST xml data directly (without key value pair) to API. The API needs certification authentication which is done here in code. Now I want to POST the data to same URL.

Here is what I want to do :

[image]
My current code is :

```
@Override
    public String demoAPI(String xmlData) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output="";
    try {
        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("path-to-pfx-file")),
                "password".toCharArray());
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientStore, "password".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("path-to-jks-file"), "password".toCharArray());
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        URL url = new URL("URL");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        con.connect();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        output = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        output = e.getMessage();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Whereas , for same url , I want to POST xmlData from method. 
How can I do that ? What should I change in the code after 
`con.setRequestMethod("POST");` ?

Comment: what happened when you tried?

Comment: I am asking that how to POST data after con.setRequestMethod("POST");
Suppose , I have edited my method to : public String demoAPI(String xmlData) . Now, how can I POST this xmlData to this URL?

Answer (score 0):

You have a url and you have some XML to post this url via HTTP. And your post request is a SOAP request, you can send this soap message in the body of this request. So nothing special or different than many developers' do. Post your soap data via http by using `java.net` or `Apache` or others. Here are the code samples to do this:

```
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
try{
    URL url = new URL("URL");
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"); // request properties, set your needs
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(xmlData.getBytes("utf-8"));
    os.close();

}catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
 }finally{
      con.disconnect();
 }
```

Another option would be to use `Apache` library. And the code:

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("URL");          
 StringEntity strEntity = new StringEntity(xmlData, "text/xml", "UTF-8");

 strEntity.setContentType("text/xml");  
 httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
 httpPost.setEntity(strEntity);  
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Hi, please see the question. I want to POST 'xmlData' in the method. Thanks if you can suggest something for the same.

Comment: What I understand is you want to **post** xml data to the specific url. Right?

Comment: Yes, actually I wanted do something like : 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(api);
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("html", html));


Can we do something like this? 
Problem is I have to use  con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()); here but can't understand how to send 'xmlData' parameter through it.
Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: opps, could you please be a clear about why do you need to do this and what is **HttpPost** and what is **api** ? Maybe what are you searching for is not what you need.

Comment: Hi, please check updated question. I have attached a screenshot. That's what I want to do. What's you idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148787/discussion-between-vyankatesh-s-repal-and-fiskra).

Comment: Hi, in the second part of your code, how I can add functionality of     con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
?   How to set SSLSocketFactory for HttpClient ? I need to use this. But when I am using that code , it's saying "SSL hand-shake error" . It needs to set SSLSocketFactory for the same. How can I do that there?

Comment: Hi, please have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209985/how-to-open-blobs-on-browser-through-service